# I cannot retrieve my current longitude and latitude in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the following code to get the lat and lang of my current location but it gives me null value in CameraPosition.. any idea why ?

```
   private void moveMapToMyLocation() {

    LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) MapsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria crit = new Criteria();


    Location loc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    CameraPosition camPos = new CameraPosition.Builder()

            .target(new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()))

            .zoom(12.8f)

            .build();

    CameraUpdate camUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos);

   mMap.moveCamera(camUpdate);



}
```

Comment: Show your full code. And make sure GPS is `Enable` on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method this will be work fine in your case

```
private void initMap() {

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            if (locationManager == null) {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }
            if (locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                isNetworkProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    location = getLastLocationByProvider(locationManager, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, getApplicationContext());
                } else if (isNetworkProviderEnabled) {
                    location = getLastLocationByProvider(locationManager, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, getApplicationContext());
                }
                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                } else {
                    if (isNetworkProviderEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100000, 1, this);
                        provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                    } else if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100000, 1, this);
                        provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                    } else {

                        alertDialog = Util.showOkDialog(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                if (Env.currentActivity != null) {
                                    if (Env.currentActivity instanceof LocationActivity) {
                                        try {
                                            gotoSettings();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                                if (alertDialog != null) {
                                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                                    alertDialog = null;
                                }

                            }
                        }, this.getResources().getString(R.string.location_service_validation));

                    }

                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }


                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                        .title(getFullAddressLine(this));
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(latitude,
                                longitude)).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this probably this should work for you.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (loc != null) {
            onLocationChanged(loc);
        } else {
            loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (loc != null)
                onLocationChanged(loc);
        }
```

onLocationChanged will be called when the location has changed.And for this you will have to implement LocationListener(Interface).
Once you have implemented the LocationListener, you will get an override method called onLocationChanged.
Through this method you will get latitude and longitude.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double dLatitude = location.getLatitude();   
    double dLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);

}
```